# Jobs stuck at queue, seems running. I'm not able to cancel or delete

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to delete jobs from my queue. I didn't see cancel button at the time so I decided to delete build. After that I can't cancel or delete stucked jobs at queue. I don't have experience with rest api but tried bulk queue remove powershell script. It removes every job in queue except stucked ones.

I've tried to bulk queue delete script

```
$PATToken = "************************"
$AuthHeader= @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PATToken)")) }

$azureDevops = "https://dev.azure.com/**********/***************"
$BuildsUrl = "$azureDevops/_apis/build/builds" 

$filterBuilds = "$($BuildsUrl)?statusFilter=notStarted&api-version=6.0"
    
(Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $filterBuilds -Headers $AuthHeader).value | % {
  $uri =  "$($BuildsUrl)/$($_.id)?api-version=6.0" # Azure Devops URI
  $body = '{"status":4}' # body 
  $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $uri -Headers $AuthHeader -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Verbose #cancel  build
  Write-Output "$($_.definition.name) cancaled"
}
```

Comment: Please check that the "$.id" is correct and try to cancel the specific build ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy use of REST API, you can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

Firstly, you can use this REST API [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to check the **status** and the **result** of your target build.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

If your pipeline is still running, the status is inProgress.
[image]

If your build is deleted while running, the status will be completed and the result will be canceled.

[image]

At the same time, you will see information about the build being deleted, such as the date of deletion, who deleted it, and the reason for deletion.

[image]

Secondly, if the result obtained through the above REST API is that your build is still running, you can cancel the build through the REST API [Builds - Update Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update-build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#buildstatus).

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

The request body should be:

```
{
    "status": "cancelling"
}
```

The Powershell scripts for your reference:

```
$token = "<Your PAT>"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/<org name>/<project name>/_apis/build/builds/<build id>?api-version=6.0"
$body = @'
{    
  "status": "cancelling"
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PATCH -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer I'll definitely use for reference, stucked jobs slowly disappeared itself after 10-12 hours